# How do I know when I found the end of the sub folder directory? c++

Tags: c++, c++17, std, std-filesystem

I am currently using a directory iterator to read through an entire directory, and it does it well because it reads through every file in any sub folder in the directory.

Is there a way to know when it has hit the end of the sub folder and will be going back to the main folder of the dir to start the next one?

for example, if my directory has:

```
mainFOLDER>SUBFOLDER>ANOTHERSUB(this is the end)
mainFOLDER>difSUBFOLDER> so on so on
mainFOLDER> whatever
```

How do I know when its hits "anothersub".

```
        if (std::filesystem::is_directory(r)) {
            fs::path path = r.path();
            std::string path_string = path.u8string();
            if (inside == false) {
                parentDir = path_string;
            }

            double clests = processDir(path_string,inside);
            if (clests != -1) {
                string newString = to_string(clests);
                finishedPaths.push_back(newString + "   " + parentDir);
            }



        }
        else if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(r)) {
            fs::path path = r.path();
            std::string path_string = path.u8string();
            double File = processFile(path_string);
            if (File != -1) {
                string newString = to_string(File);
                newString = newString + "   " + path_string;
                finishedPaths.push_back(newString);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say you're using a directory iterator do you mean a [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)?

Comment: @Kevin I updated my code. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, I build up the use of the `std::filesystem` API to get what you are asking for. Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

I explain the code as comments.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
```

```cpp
/** Print each file in the directory, separate files in different directories
 * with a horizontal line.
 */
void example1() {
  for (auto &p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(".")) {
    if (p.is_directory()) { // We could do something fancy and stop if the
                            // p.path() is what we are looking for.
      std::cout << "--------\n";
      continue;
    }
    std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
  }
}
```

```cpp
/** Let's recurse until we went down the first path along the Depth-First path.
 *
 * The easy way to do this, is to stop as soon as the first file is found. (See
 * <TODO>)
 *
 * But with a custom loop, we can potentially do more.
 */
void example2() {
  auto it = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(".");
  while (it != end(it)) { // Note: fs::end(...) argument is ignored.
    std::cout << it->path() << "\t" << it.depth() << "\n";
    /* 1. it++: This moves to the next entry. That's the default thing to do.
     * 2. it.pop(). "moves the iterator one level up in the directory hierarchy"
     * This might be useful if we are looking for specific files, and want to
     * continue in the next directory.
     * 3. it.disable_recursion_pending(): It means that it won't go into
     * subdirectories.
     */
    it++; // Code style: If we always just increment it, for(it; it!=end(it);
          // it++) is better than a while loop.
  }
}
```

```cpp
/** If I understood this correctly, you want to stop as soon you hit a directory
 * named 'anothersub'.
 */
void example3() {
  for (auto it = fs::recursive_directory_iterator("."); it != end(it); it++) {
    const auto p = it->path();
    if (it->is_directory() and p.filename() == "anothersub") {
      break;
    }
    std::cout << p << "\n";
  }
}
```

```cpp
int main() {
  example1();
  example2();
  example3();
}
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
auto depth = it.depth();
```

to track how deep it goes and call

```
it.pop();
```

when depth >  2 to get out of undesired directories and continue where you expect.